# Optimize Groovy code

Tags: groovy

I am fairly new to the Groovy/Grails arena. I recently modified some code to add the following block.

```
result.processed.each{
    def queueEntry = QueueEntry.findById(it.id)<<<START ADD>>>
    Set dates = new HashSet<Long>()

    def children = QueueEntry.findAllByParent(queueEntry)

    for(QueueEntry qe : children){
        def f = new GregorianCalendar()
        f.setTimeInMillis(DateUtils.getClearedTime(qe.entryTimestamp))
        def l = new GregorianCalendar()
        l.setTimeInMillis(DateUtils.getClearedTime(qe.exitTimestamp))
        while(f < l){
            if(f.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && f.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY){//only add weekdays
                dates.add(f.time.time)
            }
            def xx = new GregorianCalendar()
            xx.setTimeInMillis(f.time.next().time)
            f = xx
        }
        dates.add(l.time.time)
    } <<<STOP ADD>>>
    Set outsideDays = it.numberOfDaysOutsideCVB
    Set days = DateUtils.businessDaysBetweenDates(it.entryTimestamp, it.exitTimestamp)
    days.removeAll(outsideDays)
    days.removeAll(dates)
    turnTimes << days.size()
}
```

The application is now crawling.  I am obviously doing something wrong. When this is run for small data-sets it will complete slowly.  On larger sets it doesn't finish.  Prior to this change it was completing.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: typically database access can be a problem due to hibernate mappings doing something unexpected. turn on hibernate logging (debug 'org.hibernate.SQL') and see what it's doing.

Comment: Look at the code inside the while loop. It is nested inside a for loop, so you have a potential bottleneck inside this block.  Have you tried anything in here? Maybe constructing a GregorianCalender object is too costly to be doing so many times?

Comment: Are you sure your while loop exits? Also you now have 3 nested loops (each, for, while)

Comment: @zcleghern I did try changing the code to not construct the GregorianCalender object every time and it was slightly faster.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the lines of the below changes.

```
// Proposed

import static java.util.Calendar.*

// Query for all the children upfront instead of hitting
// database twice on each iteration. 
// You can also avoid N + 1 situation if children is fetched eagerly
def allChildren = QueueEntry.where {
    id in (result.processed*.id as List<Long>)
}.children.list() 

def turnTimes = result.processed.collect { entry ->
    allChildren.findAll { it.parent.id == entry.id }.collect { child ->
        Set dates = []
        new Date( child.entryTimeStamp ).upto( new Date( child.exitTimestamp ) ) {
            if ( !( it[DAY_OF_WEEK] in [ SUNDAY, SATURDAY ] ) ) {
                dates << it.time
            }
        }
        Set outsideDays = child.numberOfDaysOutsideCVB
        Set days = 
            DateUtils.businessDaysBetweenDates(
                child.entryTimestamp, 
                child.exitTimestamp 
            )

        ( days - outsideDays - dates )?.size() ?: 0
    }
}
```

**Assumptions:**

- `QueueEntry` hasMany `children`
- `entryTimestamp`/`exitTimestamp` is `java.sql.Timestamp`
- `entryTimestamp`/`exitTimestamp` are not null and `entryTimestamp` comes before `exitTimestamp`.

As Burt suggested this question best fits in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: the QueueEntry is not setup as a hasMany childern.  Is there a way to do this if it is not setup that way?

Comment: Yes. `QueueEntry.where { parent.id in (result.processed*.id as List<Long>) }.list()` should do the same instead.